# How to handle Servlet program on submitting a JSP form

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

JSP CODE:

```
Upload File:
<input name="file" type="file" id="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/><br><br>
<input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"/>   
</form>
```

I have the above JSP file which will be executed with the help of Tomcat server and this is 
stored in the following location of my system.

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\CheckURL
```

I have written a servlet program for catching the request and sending the reponse from the given JSP file.

My query here is, in which path the servlet program must be stored in my system.

And please let me know whether a servlet program can be compiled using javac NewServlet.java or it can be executed directly during runtime. Because on compiling that servelet program I get a lot of errors.

Am a beginner in java. If u can give me a detailed outlook on the above issue, it would be of great use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate question with complete answer listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [servlet tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) is a good place to start.

A few points to answer your particular questions:

- you can compile a servlet with `javac NewServlet.java` but you have to specify classpath (`-cp`) that contains the `servlet-api.jar`
- you store the `.class` file in `webapps\checkURL\WEB-INF\classes`
- you map the servlet in `WEB-INF\web.xml` using `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>`. (there is a easier way with Tomcat 7 and Servlets 3, but you are on 5.5)

Comment: Is servlet-api.jar file a compulsory one for compiling? If so, where to download the jar file?

Comment: You don't download it separately. It's part of the servletcontainer. You already have one (Tomcat). Just add path to `Tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar` to compiletime classpath. Your *actual* problem is not related to Servlets, but to basic Java. I'd suggest to learn about basic Java/Javac/Classpath first before diving into Servlets :)

Comment: @BalusC what must be given in the <form action="?"> of the JSP code?

Comment: the URL to which you have mapped the servlet (with `servlet-mapping`)